# Scraping a txt file where i have my html code in by using Python

Tags: python

I want to use as a source a text file where I have my html tags instead of the actually site `((sauce=urllib.request.urlopen('https://sitex.com').read()` to have `sauce=file.txt` where I have the tags in the file.

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
import requests

with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    soup =BeautifulSoup (r.text, "html.parser")
    for line in f:
        print(soup.find_all("a"))
```

Comment: Find all the anchor tags in a txt file that contains HTML? Post your `words.txt` data

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

words.txt:

```
<html>
<!-- Text between angle brackets is an HTML tag and is not displayed.
Most tags, such as the HTML and /HTML tags that surround the contents of
a page, come in pairs; some tags, like HR, for a horizontal rule, stand 
alone. Comments, such as the text you're reading, are not displayed when
the Web page is shown. The information between the HEAD and /HEAD tags is 
not displayed. The information between the BODY and /BODY tags is displayed.-->
<head>
<title>Enter a title, displayed at the top of the window.</title>
</head>
<!-- The information between the BODY and /BODY tags is displayed.-->
<body>
<a href="">Visit XYZ.com!</a>
<h1>Enter the main heading, usually the same as the title.</h1>
<p>Be <b>bold</b> in stating your key points. Put them in a list: </p>
<a href="">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<ul>
<li>The first item in your list</li>
<li>The second item; <i>italicize</i> key words</li>
</ul>
<p>Improve your image by including an image. </p>
<a href="">Visit ABC.com!</a>
<p><img src="http://www.mygifs.com/CoverImage.gif" alt="A Great HTML Resource"></p>
<p>Add a link to your favorite <a href="https://www.dummies.com/">Web site</a>.
Break up your page with a horizontal rule or two. </p>
<hr>
<p>Finally, link to <a href="">another page</a> in your own Web site.</p>
<!-- And add a copyright notice.-->
<p>&#169; Wiley Publishing, 2011</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and then:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "html.parser")
    for line in soup.find_all('a'):
         print(line.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Visit XYZ.com!
Visit W3Schools.com!
Visit ABC.com!
Web site
another page
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup (f.read(), "html.parser")
    for a in soup.find_all("a"):
        # do sth. here
```